# iPhone : How does the co-ordinates will be set in following code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

In one of the demo code I found following type of coding.

```
    btnLeftCard.center = CGPointMake(385.0f, 300.0f);
    btnRightCard.center = CGPointMake(385.0f, 770.0f);
```

Can anybody give me some idea for this coding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `btnLeftCard` and `btnRightCard` will be added to a parent view. The top left of that view acts as origin (0,0). The co-ordinates(x,y) will be added with respect to this point. As you go right the value of x changes and as you move below value of y changes with respect to the origin.

Answer (score 0):

[CGPointMake](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPointMake). I think it's all you need.

Answer (score 0):

btnLeftCard.center = CGPointMake(x, y);

point `(x,y)` will be the center of the `btnLeftCard`. i.e. `btnLeftCard` has a rectangular area.

Then half of its width and height will be top and left of this point and other half will be at right and bottom of this point.